# Creating custom urls for mvc4 website

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, google-analytics, custom-url

I am creating a website in MVC4 using EF5. I have a requirement for Google Analytics to create custom urls so, GA should index only these urls.

Here is what I need to customize the url:

**Original urls**:

- http://www.example.com.br/company/details
- http://www.example.com.br/company/news/this-is-a-news

**Expected custom url**:

- http://www.example.com.br/company
- http://www.example.com.br/news/this-is-a-news

Simply, any advisable changes in code or configuration in GA so, urls of lower and upper cases should be treated as same (case-insensitive urls)

Comment: What is the question? What have you tried?

Comment: I tried these: http://forums.asp.net/p/2009438/5778213.aspx?Re+How+can+we+customize+mvc4+urls